# Understanding the Lebesgue definition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have been given the following definition of the Lebesgue measure:

> Let $\mathcal{F}^1$ be the collection of sets which can be written as the finite union of half-open intervals and let $\mathcal{I}^1$ be the collection of half-open intervals.
>
> For $A\in\mathcal{F}^1$ of the form $A = (a_1,b_1]\cup\ldots\cup(a_n,b_n]$ with disjoint $((a_j,b_j])_{j=1}^{n}$ in $\mathcal{I}^1$ define $\lambda:\mathcal{F}^1\to [0,\infty)$ as the sum of the lengths:$$\lambda(A) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (b_j - a_j).$$

**Exercise:** Let $\mu:\mathcal{R}\to[0,\infty]$ be a measure such that for all $h\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mu(A+h) = \mu(A)$. Let $c =\mu((0,1]).$ Prove that for each $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mu(A) = c\lambda(A).$

*What I've tried:*

I know how to show that $\mu((a,b]) = c(b-a)$. This gets me very close to where I want to go. My problem is that I don't know what $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ looks like. Suppose $A = (-\infty, b)$. What would $\lambda(A)$ look like? Or suppose that $A = \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}A_j$; the definition in my book defines $\lambda$ only for finite sequences.

**Questions:**

- How would I solve this exercise?
- Out of curiosity, I would like to prove that $\lambda(\{x\}) = 0$, using just the above definition. I think I need to rewrite $\{x\}$ as an interval, but the only thing that comes to mind is $\{x\} = (-\infty, x)\cup(x,\infty)$. This is not a union of half-open intervals, and hence I cannot apply the definition.

(I know my second question is probably unrelated to this exercise, but I does help me better understand the Lebesgue measure.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some important information. Your exercise is to show, that for $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ it holds $\mu(A) = c\lambda(A)$... but till now this is not well defined because you only defined $\lambda$ for $A\in\mathcal{F}^1$ but not for $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

So I assume you actually have defined $\lambda$ the way written above and then consider the extension of it to $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$.

But if you consider extensions of measures you definitely had something like

> Is $\mathcal{F}{^1}$ a generator of $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ (that means $\sigma(\mathcal{F}^1) = \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$) which is stable under intersections then for all $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ it holds: $$\mu_1 = \mu_2 \text{ on } \mathcal{F}^1 \; \iff \; \mu_1 = \mu_2 \text{ on } \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$$

So it "enough" to proof the equality of both measures on the smaller generator $\mathcal{F}^1$ instead of showing it for the whole $\sigma$-algreba.

You've written:

> I know how to show that $\mu((a,b])=c(b−a)$

So you've already shown that $\mu = c\lambda$ on $\mathcal{F}^1$ and this indeed is a generator of $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ and is stable under intersections… hence you are done.

To your second question: $$\{x \} = \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} \left(x - \frac{1}{n},x\right]$$

And so you can use continuity of the measure to get: $$\lambda(\{x\}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda\left(\left(x - \frac{1}{n},x\right]\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$

Or with a monotonicity argument we have: $$\lambda(\{x\}) \le \lambda\left(\left(x - \frac{1}{n},x\right]\right) = \frac{1}{n}$$

And now use limit to get the expected result.